# lucene Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock

Tags: java

Индексирование идет всегда в один поток, иногда при получении writer'а возникает исключение:

```
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: SimpleFSLock@.../write.lock
```

и до тех пор пока не перезапущу приложение writer не получу.
P.S. удалял этот файл, все равно не помогает, ошибка остается.
В связи с этим вопрос как с этим бороться?

Comment: Может прав не хватает?

Comment: А почему тогда после перезапуска приложения все хорошо?
прав хватает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему. Не правильно организовывал закрытии writer'а
было:

```
Directory dir = ...
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir);
try {
...
} finally{
   write.close();
}
```

а нужно было:

```
Directory dir = ...
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir);
try {
...
} finally{
   try {
      writer.optimize();
      write.close();
   } finally {
      if (IndexWriter.isLocked(dir)) {
         IndexWriter.unlock(dir);
       }
   }
}
```